# Is there a way to set a path using regular expression?

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell command prompt and I want to set a location to the folder "Folder". The thing is that folder can be everywhere.

I've tried the command `Set-Location` and `Resolve-Path` but I don't get it.

I want to do something like that:

```bsh
$path = Resolve-Path ".*/Folder"
Set-Location $path
```

Where the `.*` can be all the parent folder

Any idea?

Comment: How would you know if you want C:\win32\drivers, or C:\bluetooth\drivers, or any infinite possibility? Would you want the first one? The last one? Any of them? All of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Requires PowerShell v3 or higher, you can check using `$PSVersionTable`*.*

---

```bsh
$path = (Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Folder" }).FullName
```

This will give you all the directories named `Folder` in current directory and its subdirectories recursively.

The query, however, can return multiple results so if you want to choose the first one use `[0]`. Also, to cover the case when the query returns no results, enforce returned object to be an array using `@( ... )` and check if it exists:

```
$f = @(Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Folder" })[0].FullName

if ( $f ) {
  cd $f
}
else {
  # Handle the error
}
```

`cd` is alias to `Set-Location` so you can use whichever you prefer. Important thing to remember is to use `FullName` property as it contains full path to the folder.

---

<sup>* For PowerShell versions lower than v3, use `| Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}` instead of `-Directory`</sup>

Comment: @Aguestwho'scalledRedd thanks! I usually try to add some explanation so that people can not only resolve their issue, but also learn a bit :)

Comment: well I started with PS 3-4 Months ago ;) solving problems makes me learn better. But explaing in depth is a bit harder for me. BR

Answer (score 1):

Would try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Name Folder -Recurse -Depth 10
```

Hope it helps. BR

Edit (see comments):

```
$array = Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Name Ping -Recurse -Depth 10
if($array.Count -eq 0){
    #stay
}
if($array.Count -eq 1){
    Set-Location $array
}
else{
    $array | ForEach-Object{Write-Host $_}
}
```

Comment: It returns the all found folders whithin home directory with a depth of 10 layers. The rest of your code would work for setting it as the current location. BR

Comment: @robdy Actually a quit intressting question, regarding the `-Name` parameter it wouldn't say i mixed it up with `-filter`.
Technically my idea was to check if there is an Item with the same name and iterate via `-Recurse`. How I'd use it I shall edit ;)

Comment: please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56632954/9902555) for the explanation.