# Is it possible to filter using Get-ChildItem -Name?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

In [one of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56628221/9902555) I answered recently I found interesting answer which shouldn't be working but still was. The question was about how to find specific folder recursively by its name and `cd` to it.

The [answer proposed by A guest who's called Redd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56628538/9902555) was:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Name Folder -Recurse -Depth 10
```

As per the documentation of [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6#parameters), `-Name` parameter is supposed to be `SwitchParameter` type and is responsible for returning only name (`System.String`), instead of `System.Object`.

How it's possible that the solution still works?

---

#### MCVE:

```bsh
# cd C:\SO\56628221
mkdir test, test1, test2, test3
mkdir .\test2\folder
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Name Folder -Recurse -Depth 10
```

Current output:

```
test2\folder
```

Expected output:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Folder'.
```

---

#### What have I tried?

1. First I checked that `-Path` is the only positional parameter. Apparently it is:

[image: Get-ChildItem -Path documentation]

All the other params have `Position: Named`.

2. Then I tried to switch the arguments to something like this:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ Folder -Name -Recurse -Depth 10
```

It was still working, so that was clear indication that what I'm passing to the cmdlet is not the value for `-Name`.

3. Last thing I supposed was that I just send array of strings to `-Path`. I tried to do this explicitely:

```cs
[string[]]$a = '.\','Folder'
$a.GetType()
Get-ChildItem -Path $a -Name -Recurse -Depth 10

# Output:
PS C:\SO\56628221> $a.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array


PS C:\SO\56628221> Get-ChildItem -Path $a -Name -Recurse -Depth 10
test
test1
test2
test3
test2\folder
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\SO\56628221\Folder' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Path $a -Name -Recurse -Depth 10
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\SO\56628221\Folder:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### tl;dr:

<del>Apparently there's an incorrect information in current version of `Get-ChildItem` documentation, stating that `-Filter` is no longer positional.</del>

The above is no longer true, it's been fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/pull/4450).

---

#### Long answer:

In fact, the value 'Folder' is being passed to `-Filter` parameter. Even though  [PowerShell 6 documentation says opposite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6#parameters), `-Filter` is a positional parameter. By mistake, that change was introduced in PowerShell v6+ [while PowerShell 5.1 help article for `Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1#parameters) is still correct.

The cmdlet you run:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Name Folder -Recurse -Depth 10
```

is effectively:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\" -Name -Filter "Folder" -Recurse -Depth 10
```

Even though `-Filter` parameter in `Get-ChildItem` [might be tricky in usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12914655/9902555), in that case it works perfectly and the filter is applied to only show items named 'Folder'. As that invocation doesn't specify `-File` or `-Directory`, if you run:

```bsh
# Create new file named 'Folder'
New-Item Folder
```

and then run the cmdlet once again, it'd return both file and folder which was created:

```bsh
PS C:\SO\56628221> Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Name Folder -Recurse -Depth 10
Folder
test2\folder
```

The output is exactly the same if you explicitely use `-Filter`:

```bsh
PS C:\SO\56628221> Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Name -Filter Folder -Recurse -Depth 10
Folder
test2\folder
```

Comment: I opened PR adressing that: [#4450](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/pull/4450)

Comment: Thanks for that good explanation. Somethimes I guess it's funny to see things work by coincidence :)

Comment: @Aguestwho'scalledRedd You're welcome! Feel free to upvote if you think it's valuable.

Comment: Indeed you earnt it ;)